# Converting string into usable arrays in formula in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, string, substitution, sumproduct

The goal is to output the sum of all price in Col B if the corresponding product in Col A is found in the user selection. The user selection may comprise one or multiple products, separated by comma.

I have tried 2 formula, but they both do not work because the criteria in the SUMIF is not treated as an array.

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,*"{"""&SUBSTITUTE(D2,", ",""";""")&"""}"*,B:B))

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,*CHAR(34)&SUBSTITUTE(D2,", ",CHAR(34)&","&CHAR(34))&CHAR(34)*,B:B))

Further notes:

There is only **one** cell (D2) for user selection, where they can specify the product(s) that they want to query for, separated by a comma.

Using split cells, the formula below would work, but this is not what I want because I need users to key in their selection(s) in one cell (D2). 
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,*D6:D16*,B:B))

Similarly, typing the user selection into the formula would work, but doing so would be too tedious for the user. 
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,*{"Apple";"Pear";"Grapes"}*,B:B))

[Edit] Sample Excel File:

[image]

[Edit 2]: Any clue why "{"""&SUBSTITUTE(D2,", ",""";""")&"""}" cannot be passed through the formula as array while {"Apple";"Pear";"Grapes"} works fine?

Comment: Showing some sample data and expected output would go a long way here. We are left to deduce what your data looks like by reading your equations rather.... well..... just looking at the data

Comment: For future reference, please just add a screen shot (or text) sample data right to your question. The majority of people here will not follow links posted by unknown people online for hopefully obvious reasons. If you have browsed other questions here, you have likely seen the correct way to share sample data. It leads to better & faster responses which is ultimately good for you (*help us help you situation here*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matrix formula seems to do the trick (confirm by pressing control+shift+enter):

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(A1:A4,D1)),0,B1:B4))
```